# Editing PHP function to work without filter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have taken the below code from a website which helps me output a short code to display a product table within WooCommerce. The code is created to dynamically insert the product ID and output after the short description but I need this changing so that it is a stand alone PHP function that will output exactly where I put it within my product template.

```
/**
 * Outputs WooCommerce Product Table shortcode after short description - place in functions.php
 * @param string $short_description - the original short description being passed into the filter       
 * @return string $short_description including WooCommerce Product Table shortcode
**/

function barn2media_product_table_after_short_desc($price) {
    global $product;
    if (!is_single() || !is_callable(array($product, 'get_id'))) {
        return $price;
    }
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $shortcode = "[product_table include='{$product_id}' variations='separate' lazy_load='false' columns='name,stock,price,add-to-cart,cf:ti_wishlist' cart_button='checkbox' show_quantity='true' links='none' page_length='false' search_box='false' shortcodes='true' reset_button='false' totals='false']";
    return $price . $shortcode;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'barn2media_product_table_after_short_desc', 1 );
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this function simply appends this bit of template to whatever variable is passed to it. The way it is used here it appends the value of the short description and that will in turn be used somewhere in the template.

You can try just echoing the output with an empty string input like this:

```
echo barn2media_product_table_after_short_desc('');
```

or make the function simpler like this:

```
/**
 * Outputs WooCommerce Product Table shortcode - place in functions.php
 * @return string WooCommerce Product Table shortcode
**/

function product_table() {
  global $product;
  return !is_single() || !is_callable(array($product, 'get_id')) ? '' : "[product_table include='".$product->get_id()."' variations='separate' lazy_load='false' columns='name,stock,price,add-to-cart,cf:ti_wishlist' cart_button='checkbox' show_quantity='true' links='none' page_length='false' search_box='false' shortcodes='true' reset_button='false' totals='false']";
}
```

and then include it like this:

```
$shortcode = product_table();
...
echo $shortcode;
```

`$shortcode` will contain the product table or be empty if it cannot find the product id.

ps.: I don't use woocommerce, so not sure how its templating works, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: Ahh amazing! So I have done both methods and both work to some degree. The shortcode is outputted on the front end but the shortcode is not rendering the product table. I have tested copy / pasting the outputted shortcode into the product description to test if it was correct and it does output the table. Do you know why the the shortcode is not rendering my table ? The product ID is correctly inserted for a product. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexBanks I'm not an expert on woocommerce, but most likely these bits of markup get evaluated and filled in with data before rendering the pages. In this case the contents of `$shortcode` were probably inserted after this, so you would get the raw markup, but as you said if you just insert that into your template, it will get properly rendered.